# How use ejs inside the script tag

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, ejs

I work in Node.js/Express, ejs and Postgresql.

I'm trying to insert the `<script></script>` tag EJS code that I get from the request.

Trying to do like this, but it's doesn't work:

```
<% avg_t.rows.forEach(function(avg){%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var first = JSON.stringify('<%= avg.mark %>');
console.log(first);
</script>
<%} ) %>
```

Node.js code where I execute the request :

```
const graphic1 = (req,res)=> {

    const db = new pg.Pool(te_role.client)

    db.connect(function(err, client, done){
        console.log("")
        if(err){
            return console.error('canceled')
        }

        client.query(teacher_role.show_avg,[log2,req.body.disce,req.body.numb,req.body.lett], function(err, result){
            return_data.avg_t =result 
           if (err){
           res.end()
           return console.error("canceled")
           }
           done()
        res.render('inside',{avg_t:return_data.avg_t})

})
})
}
app.get('/inside',urlencodedParser,db_te.get_graphic1)
```

And of course my full EJS code where I trying:

```
<% avg_t.rows.forEach(function(avg){%>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var first = JSON.stringify('<%= avg.mark %>');
    console.log(first);
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', first],
        ['Onions', 1],
      ]);
      var barchart_options = {
        title: 'Barchart: How Much Pizza I Ate Last 
        Night ',width:400,height:300,legend: '
        none '};
        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
      }
  </script>

<%} ) %>
```

Comment: `but it's doesn't work` - what does this mean?

Comment: @hoangdv When I tried to do this `var first = JSON.stringify('<%= avg.mark %>');
console.log(first);` it didn't work. console.log does not output anything.
It doesn't give out errors, but just nothing happens

Comment: `View Page Source` to see the generated html, and you can see what is going on?

Comment: @hoangdv The page loads,but the graph I would like to draw doesn't appear

Comment: `avg_t.rows` is empty array

Comment: @hoangdv How can this be resolved ? Could you show me a small example, please

Comment: @hoangdv Sorry for writing again. I just really need it. I can't figure out how to solve the problem myself....

Comment: `res.render('inside', {avg_t: {rows: [{mark: 1}]}})`